# jsonwebtoken with custom header and claims

Tags: node.js, jwt, app-store, auth0

Authenticating to [Apple App Store Server](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/generating_tokens_for_api_requests) and I've got headers as follows

```js
{
  alg: "HS256", 
  typ: "JWT",
  kid: kid
}
```

and claims with values as follows:

```js
{
  iss: issuerID,
  aud: audience,
  ...
}
```

In the [node-jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) library I'm trying to sign with the header as payload and claims as options:

`jwt.sign(jwtHeader(), key, jwtClaims(), cb)`

This ends up throwing exceptions such as `Error: "iss" is not allowed in "options"`. Otherwise, keep getting `401 Unauthorized` response. How may I use this library to appropriately sign my header and claims?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you sign a token with node-jsonwebtoken you normally just get the default header

```js
{
  alg: "HS256", 
  typ: "JWT"
}
```

If you need any extra values in the header, e.g. the key-id `kid`, you can add them in the `options.header` object. You need to pass the options object as a third parameter to the sign function:

```js
const keyId = 123
const jwtOptions = {
    header: { kid: keyId }
}
```

The options object is also the place where you can add the expirations time, set a different signature algorithm (default is `HS256`) or switch off the auto-generated timestamp `iat`(issued at).

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

// define the payload
const payload = {
    iss: "issuerID",
    aud: "audience"
}

const keyId = 123

// extra header values can be defined in the header parameter in the options:
const jwtOptions = {
    expiresIn: 300,      // 300 seconds
    //algorithm: 'HS512',  // only necessary if you want a different value than 'HS256' 
    //notimestamp: true, // don't added timestamp iat (issued at)
    header: { kid: keyId
            }
}
  
// pass the options as third parmater (optional)
const token = jwt.sign(payload, "supersecret", jwtOptions);
```

result:

```js
header:
{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "JWT",
  "kid": "123"
}

payload:
{
  "iss": "issuerID",
  "aud": "audience",
  "iat": 1630044877,
  "exp": 1630044887
}
```